# Simple speed up of C++ OpenMP kernel

Tags: c++, opencv, openmp

This function calculates the standard deviation of a patch, given a kernel size and greyscale OpenCV image. The middle pixel of the patch is kept if stdev of the patch is below the given threshold, else it is rejected. This is done for each pixel except the border.

I have never worked with OpenMP or optimization of C++, so all help is welcome. I'm probably doing some very stupid things that slow down the process drastically. It doesn't need to be the fastest, but I think some easy tricks will significantly speed it up.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/photo/photo.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "utils.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <numeric>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
Mat low_pass_filter(Mat img, int threshold, int kernelSize)
{
    unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(img.data);
    Mat output = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC1);
    unsigned char *output_ptr = (unsigned char*)(output.data);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = (kernelSize - 1) / 2; i < img.rows - (kernelSize - 1) / 2; i++){
        for (int j = (kernelSize - 1) / 2; j < img.cols - (kernelSize - 1) / 2; j++){
            double sum, m, accum, stdev;
            vector<double> v;
            v.reserve(kernelSize*kernelSize);
            // Kernel Patch
            for (int kx = i - (kernelSize - 1) / 2; kx <= i + (kernelSize - 1) / 2; kx++){
                for (int ky = j - (kernelSize - 1) / 2; ky <= j + (kernelSize - 1) / 2; ky++){
                    v.push_back((double)input[img.step * kx + ky]);//.at<uchar>(kx, ky));
                }
            }
            sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0.0);
            m = sum / v.size();

            accum = 0.0;
            std::for_each(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [&](const double d) {
                accum += (d - m) * (d - m);
            });

            stdev = sqrt(accum / (v.size() - 1));
            if (stdev < threshold){
                output_ptr[img.step * i + j] = input[img.step * i + j];
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the updated code snippet was posted around the same time that the answer was submitted, so I've removed it in case it wasn't reviewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector v is not required.  Instead of adding items to it, iterate directly over your source array, <strike>and then use [variance = E(v²) / E(v)²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition)</strike> so that your inner code becomes:

```
        double sum = 0;
        int n = kernelSize * kernelSize;
        // Kernel Patch
        for (int kx = ...) {
            for (int ky = ...) {
                double d = (double)input[img.step * kx + ky]);
                sum += d;
            }
        }
        const double mean = sum/n;

        double sum2 = 0;
        for (int kx = ...) {
            for (int ky = ...) {
                double d = (double)input[img.step * kx + ky]);
                sum2 += (d - mean) * (d - mean);
            }
        }
        const double stddev = sqrt(sum2/n);
        if (stddev < threshold) {
            ...;
        }
```

After that, consider that the sum of elements centred around (x+1,y) can be found from the result for (x,y) simply by subtracting all the elements in the previous left-hand column, and adding all the elements in the new right-hand column.  An analogous operation works vertically.

Also, check your compiler options - are you auto-vectorizing loops, and using SIMD instructions (if available)?

Comment: Please don't suggest the "mean of square minus square of mean" formula for the variance, it is _not_ a good idea for numerics (it is only useful for pencil-and-paper math): http://davegiles.blogspot.com/2015/06/statistical-calculations-numerical.html // There's also a typo, "/" should be "-", but this is beside the point, since this formula should not be used on a computer anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Matt - absolutely right.  Don't do this!